# sql server concating or replacing, which one is better (faster)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to generate a very long  procedure every time for a reporting system, so i created a template  for my procedure and replacing the parts are needed to, but i could do it with Concat or +(&)

for example:

```
    set @query = '... and (      
         --@InnerQueries 
    )'

    set @query = replace(@query,'--@InnerQueries',@otherValues)
```

vs

```
set @query += ' and exists (...)'
if(@xxx is not null)
    set @query += 'and not exists (...)'
```

with replace approach it's more readable and maintainable for me, but for sake of optimization, what about Concat and attaching string together?
with replace: there are a lot of searching but less string creation
and with concat: lot's of string creation but no searching
so any idea?

Comment: CONCAT() and REPLACE() both are different from each other.....

Comment: You might want to add the code for both methods you are trying as we don't know what "replace approach" is

Comment: @akhileshsingh both can be used to create dynamic string (sql) , updated the question for more clarifying

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about using CONCAT or REPLACE to build an SQL then run it. If ultimately you'll process fewer than 100 REPLACEments, I'd go with that approach rather than CONCAT because it's more readable.

If however, you're talking about using concat/replace to create report output data and you will e.g. be carrying out 100 REPLACE operations per row on a million rows, I'd do the CONCAT route

Comment: i'm creating a dynamic sql, (it's not a big problem for my scenario), more wandering if any comparison exists, maybe tried to create one by myself

Comment: You’ll have to do billions of replacements/concats before enough of a difference emerges to even start making a dent in the time you’ve put into wondering about it so far. I’d do whichever seemed more readable and maintainable and move onto putting my energy into something else

Comment: here is the interesting part, even with 20 time, the difference so huge (it's all about text length) , i upload the code in minutes

Comment: If it takes you minutes to upload a dynamic sql you created, that must be one enormous sql. It would probably be better to find another way of doing that query than use such a huge sql

Comment: please look at the answer, i really like to see another opinion here

Comment: 200 string replacements in sql server does not take minutes; something is wrong somewhere, such as a bug meaning the length of the replaced text is increasing exponentially with every iteration. I'm not in a position to run your code but I urge you to make a test that is representative of your real world example

Answer (score -1):

**update 2:**
there could be something missing here:
if i change first variable :@sourceText_Replace
to a max value of 8000 character, and continue to add to it:

```
set @sourceText_Replace += '8000 character length'
set @sourceText_Replace +=@sourceText_Replace
set @sourceText_Replace +=@sourceText_Replace
set @sourceText_Replace +=@sourceText_Replace
set @sourceText_Replace +=@sourceText_Replace
set @sourceText_Replace +=@sourceText_Replace
set @sourceText_Replace +=@sourceText_Replace
```

it works fine, even if go up until: 16384017 character length

so any idea here is as good as mine

**orginal answer:**

to summarize (and if i didnt make any mistakes):

if you are searching in a long text, dont even think about using replace, it took seconds not milliseconds, but for concat obviously does not make any difference

in the blew code, in first try(small text), i just used variables default values and did not append to them,
but for second try(long Text) , i just append result from previous loop run

for long text, i did not bothered to run the loop more than 20 time, because it took over minutes.

smallText: set @destSmallText_Replace **=**

longText: set @destSmallText_Replace **+=**

[image: comparisionSheet]

here is the code for test:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

drop table if exists #tempReplace
drop table if exists #tempConcat

create table #tempReplace
(
    [txt] nvarchar(max) not null
)
create table #tempConcat
(
    [txt] nvarchar(max) not null
)



declare  @sourceText_Replace  nvarchar(max) = 'small1 text to replace @textToBeReplaced after param text'
declare  @text_Replace   nvarchar(max) = @sourceText_Replace

declare  @textToSearch  nvarchar(max) = '@textToBeReplaced'
declare  @textToReplace  nvarchar(max) = 'textToBeReplaced'

declare  @concat_Start  nvarchar(max) = 'small1 text to replace'
declare  @concat_End  nvarchar(max) = 'after param text'
declare  @text_Concat   nvarchar(max) = @concat_Start


declare @whileCounter int =0
declare @maxCounter int = 5

declare @startTime datetime = getdate();
declare @endTime datetime = getdate();

begin
    set @startTime = getDate();

    while(@whileCounter <=@maxCounter)
    begin
    --long text
    set @text_Replace += replace(@sourceText_Replace,@textToSearch,@textToReplace + convert(nvarchar(10), @whileCounter)) + @textToSearch
    --small text
    --set @text_Replace = replace(@sourceText_Replace,@textToSearch,@textToReplace + convert(nvarchar(10), @whileCounter)) + @textToSearch

    --print @destSmallText_Replace 

    insert into #tempReplace values(@text_Replace)
    set @whileCounter+=1
    end
    set @endTime = getDate();
    print 'passedTime ' + Convert(nvarchar(20),  DATEPART(millisecond, @endTime) - DATEPART(millisecond, @startTime))

end

begin
    set @whileCounter = 0;


    set @startTime = getDate();
    while(@whileCounter <=@maxCounter)
    begin
    set @text_Concat += concat(@concat_Start,@textToReplace + convert(nvarchar(10), @whileCounter),@concat_End) + @textToSearch
    --print @sourceSmallText_Concat 

    insert into #tempConcat values(@text_Concat)
    set @whileCounter+=1
    end

    set @endTime = getDate();
    print 'passedTime ' + Convert(nvarchar(20),    DATEPART(millisecond, @endTime) - DATEPART(millisecond, @startTime))
end
```